# Tooltip jumping if I keep disabled vertical scrollbar visible after opening modal - Materializecss

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using materializecss in my project and I came across the following issue:

On long pages with vertical scrollbar, scrollbar is removed by opening a modal and it causes the content to jump to the right a little. Normally that's not a big deal but I am also using masonry grid and removing the scrollbar causes funny and unwanted animations (masonry is reinitialized on window resize).

After some research and playing around I actually got pretty good results in keeping disabled (empty) scrollbar on modal open:

https://jsfiddle.net/mizurnix/49wkuvwe/

I wrap all my content in `.wrapper` class to separate it from modals and tooltips (which are direct descendants of body). Then I add `.modal-open` class to `html` tag via js and apply following css:

```
.modal-open {
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
  }
  .wrapper {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

In addition, I set `.wrapper`'s top to negative value, equal to current scroll position. Together with `position: fixed;` it ensures background content to stay at current scroll position:

```
(function( $ ) {
    var oldOpen = $.fn.openModal;
    $.fn.extend({
        openModal: function(options) {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(this).data('scroll-position', scroll);
            $('.wrapper').css('top',0 - scroll);
            $('html').addClass('modal-open');
            oldOpen.call(this, options);
        }
    });
    var oldClose = $.fn.closeModal;
    $.fn.extend({
        closeModal: function(options) {
            $('.wrapper').css('top','initial');
            $('html').removeClass('modal-open');
            oldClose.call(this, options);
            $('body').scrollTop($(this).data('scroll-position'));
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

However, there is one issue remaining - in my jsfiddle, if you scroll down a little, hover over a button to cause a tooltip open and click the button, you will see the tooltip jumps downward, I believe with same amount of pixels as is your current scroll position. It would be great to prevent that somehow.